# MSAccess not opening database when started using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()

Tags: vb.net, process, ms-access-2010

I am having trouble to start an Access Database (msaccess.mdb) programmatically using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start().

This is the Scenario:

1. vb.net aspx page starts [installpath]\cmd\ERPImport.exe
2. ERPImport.exe reads settings from a SQL server db (pgmname, params, execdir) an uses again process.start() to start the batch file  [installpath]\cmd\Import.cmd
3. Import.cmd contains only these 3 lines:

`G:
cd \ESVONIX
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\msaccess.exe" "G:\ESVONIX\ESVONIX.mdb" /runtime`

The esvonix.mdb is programmed to start some data manipulation in the startforms OnOpen Event. The startform is set in the db settings.

Now for the strange part:

- if I start Import.cmd with double click from Windows Explorer everything is fine
- if I start ERPImport.exe (with a Connection string as the Parameter it expects) from a command line it works fine

BUT: if I start ERPImport.exe from within my vb.net page, it will start Import.cmd correctly and Import.cmd will start msaccess.exe (as I can see in taskmgr). However, Access does NOT open the database (no ldb file created) and does not start processing. It "hangs around" in the taskmgr with 0 cpu time used. After killing msaccess.exe from taskmgr the rest works fine again: Import.cmd completes, ERPImport completes, the aspx page Shows the result.

I have tried a large number of different Settings in process.startinfo, but the result is always the same, regardless of my Settings.

Any ideas are very welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps Access is getting stuck because it expects to be run under an account that belongs to a person and therefore has a "normal" environment with a User Profile, a user branch in the Windows Registry (HKCU), etc.. If your ASPX script is running in an IIS Application Pool that belongs to a system account (e.g., "Network Service") then that might cause Access to hang because it is trying to manipulate those "regular user" resources that may not exist. You might try tweaking the Application Pool settings to use a non-system ("real person") account and see if that helps.

Comment: thanks Gord, but the user account of the ApplicationPool is already set to a "norrmal" user account which is able to log in to the Server and can run Access and the included code. In fact, I did the tests described in the question under exactly this same user.

Answer (score 1):

After changing from a full Office Installation to Access Runtime the Problem persisted, even without the /runtime Parameter in the call to Access.
However, the Problem disappeared and Access was called and processed correctly with the command line Switch /save after the database Name in the command line.

UPDATE - Solved
Unfortunately the /safe Parameter (requesting Access to start in Safe mode) did not fix the Problem. The process did run exactly once after adding the parameter and then went back to the previous behaviour.

The solution finally was to change the ApplicationPool settings to "LoadUserProfile = true". There are a number of questions on SO dealing with this Parameter. The exact reason in my case is not clear, but if it works ...

UPDATE July 11, 2017
Same Problem in a different user Environment. This time Windows 2012 Server.
Setup worked with the combination of /safe Parameter when calling msaccess.exe and Setting the application pool to LoadUserProfile=true (in advanced Settings)

Comment: Thanks for posting your findings. Could you please take a brief moment and edit your answer to explain what the `/save` switch is supposed to do and how you discovered it?

Comment: Today I receive different results from yesterday. Maybe the solution is not yet correctly described. I will update as soon as I have a real and persisting solution to describe